# OCMockito verify with any arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, ocmockito

I'm trying to verify that a function on a mock object is NOT called at all with ANY parameters.

The function on the object I'm mocking is...

```
- (void)registerUserWithUsername:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password;
```

I'd like to verify that the function is NOT called if the username is blank.

i.e.

```
[mockService registerUserWithUsername:@"" password:@"Password"];

[verify(mockService, never()) registerWithUsername:....... password:.......];
```

I'm just not sure what to put in the ...... bits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To specify that it's never called with any parameters, use the `anything()` matcher:

```
[verify(mockService, never()) registerWithUsername:(id)anything() password:(id)anything()];
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for primitive types?

Comment: @Zorayr See [How do you specify matchers for non-object arguments?](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito#how-do-you-specify-matchers-for-non-object-arguments)